# How to make function in excel effect to other excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Now I got stuck with making function excel that can effect to other excel sheet in the same page. For example, I have sheet1 and sheet2. Now I have function in sheet1 and I want to make it effect to sheet2. I input data to sheet1 (=B1,C1), but the effect was effect to sheet2. I am very wonder how to make two sheet can commune each other. Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: have you try my answer? .. any comment ?

Answer (score 0):

`Sheets("Sheet Name")` provides you the reference to adjacent sheet. You can then `Activate` it and act on it as `ActiveSheet`. Or, directly fill cells there.

Comment: Your explanation is too short, I completely don't understand!

Answer (score 0):

To make direct effect, you can use `Worksheet_Change` event ..

So, you can make code in Sheet1 .. sample for multiply B1 & C1 and the result in Sheet2!D1 ..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim y as Integer

  y = Target.Row   
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & format(y)) = Range("B" & format(y)).Value * Range("C" & format(y)).Value 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this VBA? You may just put a formula in sheet2 cells refering cells in Sheet1:

```
=Sheet1!A1
```